# What does 'wakeups' number represent when dumping all alarms using adb

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakeup

When i dump all alarms using the command *adb shell dumpsys alarm*, I see the number "wakeups" (17 below).

What does this mean - it is the number of times this  app has already woken up the phone or the number of times it is scheduled to wake up in the future.

If this is a cumulative tally of the past wakeups by this app - does this number ever get reset?

Alarm Stats:

+442ms running, 17 wakeups:

Answer (score 1):

It shows how many times the alarm has fired. The phone may have been awake when it fired.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question + this should be a comment.

Comment: It answers the first question. I don't know answer to the second one.

Comment: Btw, hello. You seem to be experienced in android and c++, at least. Nice to meet you, Getting 1k+ rep in 6 days, wow.